# Rails log management

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm starting to get overwhelmed using VI to search through my logs to chase down login errors and would like a better solution. I know Newrelic is highly recommended, though was wondering if there was something free I could try for the short term.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you need an exception notification system (if you are tracking errors). Check out http://www.getexceptional.com/ or http://hoptoadapp.com/. Also, New Relic offers a free plan "bronze" so you can get started using it for free.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't wish to use a third-party service, you can also take a look at [ErrorNot](http://github.com/errornot/ErrorNot).
It does the same as hoptoad but is an open source project that you install wherever you want (requires rails and a mongodb database).